# Opera text-align:justify by font-size:0

Tags: opera, font-size, text-align, justify

I had a problem, I'm making a web page and I'm using text-align:justify in several parts of the web, everything fine, it works well in all the browsers I have tested it but opera, in there everythig gets messy and out of margins, some links in the menu those in left side appear but can't be selected, in other words they don't appear to be links, I'm using a hack to justify the li elements of my ul with an extra li span class="strecth"> to make it works, I think, that is a well know hack, using

```
font-size:0;
text-align: justify;
-ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
text-justify: distribute-all-lines
```

in the ul element and

```
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1
```

in the li elements. 
So what's the question?, there is no question. This is the solution to make it works in opera. I have a menu wrapper, it has font-size:0px and the ul element is inside a nav id="#menu" which also has font-size:0px

```
#menuwrapper{  max-width:970px;
           margin:20px auto 0px auto;
       font-size:0px;
       text-align:left;
       padding:0px;}

#menu ul{  padding:0px;
       margin:0px;
       clear:both;
           font-size:0;
       text-align: justify;
       -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
       text-justify: distribute-all-lines;}
```

testing I found out that the font-size was the problem but if i change that the rest of the page change, so I change this only for opera whith: noindex:-o-prefocus, #menu ul{font-size:1px; in this way.

```
#menuwrapper{   max-width:970px;
        margin:20px auto 0px auto;
        font-size:0px;
        text-align:left;
        padding:0px;}

noindex:-o-prefocus, #menuwrapper {font-size:1px;}

#menu ul{   padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        clear:both;
        font-size:0;
        text-align: justify;
        -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
        text-justify: distribute-all-lines;}
```

noindex:-o-prefocus, #menu ul{font-size:1px;}

In fact no parent must have font-size:0px to text-algn:justify to works.
An thats it, please excuese my English, is not my language

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding :

```
noindex:-o-prefocus, #menuwrapper {font-size:1px;}
```

do not fix the problem (I test it on linux). When I set font size to 2px it start works. Finally I used:

```
noindex:-o-prefocus, #menuwrapper {font-size:100%;}
```

and everything works like a charm.

Comment: I discovered problem with IE11 when font-size is set to 0. Finally I do not use "noindex:-o-prefocus, #menuwrapper {font-size:100%;}" at all. Instead of set font-size: 0 in basic element style i set font-size: 100% for all. I test it on FF (Win, Lnx) Opera (Win, Lnx), Chrome (Win, Lnx), Safari (ipad), android browser, IE9 and IE11.